# Can we use Case When created column in join condition while joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, conditional-statements, case-when

If we use case when created column in join condition... code runs. But is it correct? If it is how is this executed?

```
select *,
case when position('/' in pax_name)>0 
         then SUBSTR(pax_name, 1, position('/' in pax_name)- 1) 
          end as **lastname**, 
    CASE WHEN position('/' in pax_name)>0 
         THEN SUBSTR(pax_name, position('/' in pax_name) + 1, LENGTH(pax_name))  
         END as **firstname**
from o
inner join m
on o.record=m.record
and o.pax_first_name = **firstname**
and o.pax_last_name = **lastname**
```

Comment: No, you can't. MySQL special is to use HAVING clause for this.

Answer (score 0):

The column aliases defined in the `select` are not available in most of the query at the same level of the `select`.  In particular, they are not available for the `where` or `from` clauses.

You can accomplish this using `having`:

```
select *,
       (case when position('/' in pax_name) > 0 
             then SUBSTR(pax_name, 1, position('/' in pax_name)- 1) 
        end) as lastname, 
       (case when position('/' in pax_name)  >0 
             then substr(pax_name, position('/' in pax_name) + 1, length(pax_name))  
        end) as firstname
from o inner join
     m
     on o.record = m.record
having o.pax_first_name = firstname and
       o.pax_last_name = lastname;
```

You can simplify the logic.  I think you simply want:

```
select *,
       (case when pax_name like '%'
             then substring_index(pax_name, '/', 1)
        end) as firstname,
       (case when pax_name like '%'
             then substring_index(pax_name, '/', -1)
        end) as lastname
from o inner join
     m
     on o.record = m.record
having o.pax_first_name = firstname and
       o.pax_last_name = lastname;
```

I would also recommend dispensing with the having, so:

```
select *,
       (case when pax_name like '%'
             then substring_index(pax_name, '/', 1)
        end) as firstname,
       (case when pax_name like '%'
             then substring_index(pax_name, '/', -1)
        end) as lastname
from o inner join
     m
     on o.record = m.record
        m.pax_name = concat_ws('/', o.pax_first_name, o.pax_last_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

use subquery

```
select o1.* from (
select *,
case when position('/' in pax_name)>0 
         then SUBSTR(pax_name, 1, position('/' in pax_name)- 1) 
          end as **lastname**, 
    CASE WHEN position('/' in pax_name)>0 
         THEN SUBSTR(pax_name, position('/' in pax_name) + 1, LENGTH(pax_name))  
         END as firstname
from o
) o1 inner join m
on o1.record=m.record
and o1.pax_first_name = firstname
and o1.pax_last_name =lastname
```